# Rails v3.2.1 Action Mailer has body text repeated for each attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, email-attachments

This is my Action Mailer with one method.

```
class Clientmailer   < ActionMailer::Base

  def sendinvoicesemail(eminvs,emref)
    @client = Client.find(eminvs[0].invclientid)
    recipients = ''
    3.times do |num|
      recipients += eval('@client.clientemail'+(num + 1).to_s) + ',' if  eval('@client.clientinvemail' + (num + 1).to_s) == true
    end
    fpath = AppParam.val('SITEBASEADDR')+'/public/invs/'
    eminvs.each do |inv|
      fname = inv.invsuppjoinedname+'_'+inv.invno.to_s+'.pdf'
      mail.attachments[fname] = File.read(fpath+fname)
    end
    mail(
      :to => recipients,
      :from => "GourmIndia Services GmbH Group<purvez@nexar.free-online.co.uk>",
      :subject => "Invoices from GourmIndia Group / " + emref.to_s
      #:sent_on => Time.now
    )
  end

  end
```

This is my call to Clientmailer

```
def self.sendinvoicesemail
  emref = AppParam.val('EMAILREF').to_i
  externalclients.each do |cl|
    eminvs = cl.invoices.emailable
    next if eminvs.length == 0
    emref += 1
    Clientmailer.sendinvoicesemail(eminvs,emref).deliver
    AppParam.set("EMAILREF",emref)
   end
end
```

And finally this is my html body text in: sendinvoicesemail.html.erb

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> 
            Attached to this email you will find invoices for services recently supplied by GourmIndia Group Companies.
        </p> 
        <p>
            Please ensure that you pay in the correct currency, into the correct account and within <%= @client.clientcreditdays.to_s %> days from invoice date as per our agreement.
        </p> 
        <p>
            Thank you for booking with GourmIndia Group.
        </p>
    </body> 
</html>
```

The Problem:  Body text keeps getting repeated for the number of invoices in the attachment.

I'm working with Rails v3.2.1

Please can someone tell me what it is I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: This answer helped me with the same issue! You should post it as an answer and then just set it as correct. Otherwise it makes the question confusing. I'd add it as an answer but I don't want to be seen as taking credit for it.

Comment: @jpcamara You could have posted the solution as a community wiki answer (by ticking the small box under the answer), then it is clear you are not taking credit for the answer. I have done it for you.

Answer (score 0):

([Solved in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))

The OP write:

> SOLUTION:
>
> Within `Clientmailer` I changed the line:
>
> ```
> mail.attachments[fname] = File.read(fpath+fname)
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> attachments[fname] = File.read(fpath+fname)
> ```
>
> I don't fully understand why this should be so if anyone can throw some light on this it would be useful.